# Implementing iota in ruby

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, functional-programming, scheme, combinators

I apologize in advance for asking this question again. I asked this question previously with respect to a Haskell implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11960809/1177119), but I'm still having difficulty wrapping my head around how this works. Also, I find the concept of a minimalistic programming language absolutely fascinating and can't get away from it... anyways, this is no place to be nostalgic about the beauty of functional programming.

So! I found a website about esoteric programming languages and discovered Iota. Iota is arguably the smallest functional language. You can read more about it here: ["Iota and Jot: the simplest languages?"](http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Iota/) Here is the reference implementation of Iota in Scheme:

```
(let iota ()
   (if (eq? #\* (read-char)) ((iota)(iota))
       (lambda (c) ((c (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (z) ((x z)(y z))))))
                    (lambda (x) (lambda (y) x))))))
```

But, when I try something equivalent in elegance to the Scheme implementation in Ruby it ends up spitting out a "bad proc". Can anyone help me understand why Ruby is behaving this way and how this can be implemented better. While trying to get this to work, I kept `S`, `K`, and `BASIS` separate just for readability.

I included two tests at the bottom. The first should return `I` (`BASIS[BASIS]`), but instead it returns a proc that doesn't produce the same result as `I`. The second test should return `K`, but instead it returns an error.

```
S = lambda {|f| lambda {|g| lambda {|x| f[x][g[x]] }}}
K = lambda {|x| lambda {|y| x }}
BASIS = lambda {|c| c[S][K] }

iota = lambda{|s|
   s = s.chars
   i = lambda {
      if s.next == '*'
         i[i]
      else
         BASIS
      end
   }
}

p BASIS[BASIS][1]         # => 1
p iota["*ii"][1]          # => #<Proc:0x000000010016b290>

p K[1][2]                 # => 1
p iota["*i*i*ii"][1][2]   # => line 3:in `[]': can't convert Proc into Integer (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to sepp2k I think I figured it out, here's the answer for anyone who's interested:

```
S = lambda {|f| lambda {|g| lambda {|x| f[x][g[x]] }}}
K = lambda {|x| lambda {|y| x }}
BASIS = lambda {|c| c[S][K] }

iota = lambda{|s|
   s = s.chars
   i = lambda {
      if s.next == '*'
         i[][i[]]
      else
         BASIS
      end
   }
   i[]
}

p BASIS[BASIS][1]          # => 1
p iota["*ii"][1]           # => 1

p K[1][2]                  # => 1
p iota["*i*i*ii"][1][2]    # => 1
```

Answer (score 4):

On line 9, you're calling `i[i]`, but `i` doesn't take any arguments - only the lambda returned by `i` does. So you should call `i` with no arguments and then call the result of calling `i` with `i` as its argument, i.e. `i[][i]`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. It's still returning the wrong values for `K` and `I` (in iota) though. For `I` it's returning a `proc` object and for `K` it's returning `2`... which might be the right value, although I would expect it to return `1`.